# Solving Integer Multiplication via Divide and Conquer

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

I'm given two n-bit numbers, $a$ and $b$. The goal is to compute the product using divide and conquer.

One approach involves rewriting $a$ and $b$ as follows:

[image]

I don't understand the intuition behind this way of representing $a$ and $b$. What does it mean by "all n/2-bit numbers"?

I'm assuming there must be some connection between $2^{n/2}$ and the fact that the fact that $x$, $y$, $w$, and $z$ are all n/2-bit numbers since both include $n/2$, but what's the significance? What does it mean?

Comment: The Wikipedia article [Karatsuba algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm) should help explaining the situation to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a$ is $n$ bits long, you are just splitting it in half to get $x$ and $y$.  "All $\frac n2$ bit numbers" refers to $x,y,w,z$, which are all $\frac n2$ bits long.  So if $a=10011101_2$, which has $n=8$ bits, we have $a=2^4 \cdot 1001_2+1101_2$, so $x=1001_2, y=1101_2$.  You split $b$ the same way and reorgainze the multiplication.  Now instead of one multiply where both numbers are $n$ bits you have $4$ multiplies where each number has $\frac n2$ bits plus a couple of shifts which are represented by the multiplication by a power of $2$.  Whether this is an improvement depends on your processor.